# Find SARIMAX AIC and pdq values, statsmodels

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, statsmodels

I'm trying to find the values of p,d,q and the seasonal values of P,D,Q using statsmodels as "sm" in python.

The data set i'm using is a csv file that contains time series data over three years recording the energy consumption. The file was split into a smaller data frame in order to work with it. Here is what df_test.head() looks like.

```
                      time  total_consumption
122400 2015-05-01 00:01:00            106.391
122401 2015-05-01 00:11:00            120.371
122402 2015-05-01 00:21:00            109.292
122403 2015-05-01 00:31:00             99.838
122404 2015-05-01 00:41:00             97.387
```

Here is my code so far.

```
#Importing the timeserie data set from local file
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\path\Name of the file.csv")

#Rename the columns, put time as index and assign datetime to the column time
df.columns = ["time","total_consumption"]
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df.set_index('time')

#Select test df (there is data from the 2015-05-01 2015-06-01)
df_test = df.loc[(df['time'] >= '2015-05-01') & (df['time'] <= '2015-05-14')]

#Find minimal AIC value for the ARIMA model integers
p = range(0,2)
d = range(0,2)
q = range(0,2)

pdq = list(itertools.product(p,d,q))

seasonal_pdq = [(x[0], x[1], x[2], 12) for x in list(itertools.product(p,d,q))]

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(df_test,
                                            order=param,
                                            seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                                            enforce_invertibility=False)

            results = mod.fit()
            print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))

        except:
            continue
```

When I try to run the code as it is, the program doesn't even acknowledge the "for" loop. But when I take out the

```
try:
except:
    continue
```

the program gives me this error message

```
ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with np.asarray(data).
```

How could I remedy that and is there a way to automate the process directly output the parameters with the lowest AIC value (without having to look for it throught all the possibilities).

Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to SO! 
please read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem

Comment: What is the problem with the question ?

Comment: Try to reduce the code to only include the necessary lines that generate the same error. You can use a temporary variable with a hard coded value just before the line after which you suspect causes error.

Comment: Ok, i will do that. Do you sugest me to repost another question or to edit this one ?

Comment: You should edit this one only. It again appears at top of the questions list as if it was a new question.

Comment: @quentin_P : did you find a solution to automatically find the parametersr with the lowest AIC? Im looking for the same thing and it would same me a lot of time if you could share your solution